# How do you color code clips in the VSE?

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor

Is there a option or addon that allows you to change the colors of clips in the VSE, so it is easier to categorize them, for instance changing the 1st clip to red then changing another added video(the 2nd clip) to yellow. I'm working on a project that will borrows from tens of mp4 files and I don't think regular naming will categorize them.

Comment: No, there is not native way to change a colour of a strip. Blender uses many type of strips already colorised, opposability to colorised them individually sounds like a mess. But I can imagine have some color strip at bottom part. You can search if there is an add-on (not sure if even possible).

Comment: If you are going to work in a complex project use a different video editing app. Blender's VSE is too basic, and not very flexible or responsive. Spare yourself the frustration.